# Is this Function of Product of variable and Ratio of CDF and PDF of Standard Normal Distribution Convex?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis

Let $G\left(x\right)=x\frac{\phi\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$. Here, $\phi$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF, respectively. Is $G\left(x\right)$ convex? It has been shown earlier that $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\phi\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$ is convex.

Please provide proof that $G\left(x\right)=x^{2}+x\frac{\phi\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$ is convex $\forall x>0 $. Here, $\phi$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF, respectively.

## STEPS TRIED

I have tried the calculus method and have a formula for the second derivate, but am not able to show that it is positive $\forall x > 0$. Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Please provide proof that $G\left(x\right)=x^{2}+x\frac{\phi\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$ is convex $\forall x>0 $. Here, $\phi$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF, respectively. 

#STEPS TRIED

I have tried the calculus method and have a formula for the second derivate, but am not able to show that it is positive $\forall x > 0$. Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: The "STEPS TRIED" does not display. Please type using Mathjax so we can see what you tried. Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hey @KittyL … Please note this is a rather old question …  But I believe, it is not convex as we also see in the graph below. I used the simple derivative test to try, but was not able to show this.

Comment: Sorry, it was in the review queue, so I commented absentmindedly.

Comment: But thank you for the pointer … It will be useful for other questions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. $\frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}$ is positive, decreasing and convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$, but $x\cdot\frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}$ is increasing in a right neighbourhood of zero and decreasing for large values of $x$. Since it is positive on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x\cdot\frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}=0$, it must have an inflection point somewhere. For instance, the inflection point is near $x=1.6$:

$\hspace1in$ [image]

Comment: Thanks Jack. How about $F\left(x\right)=x^{2}+x\frac{\phi\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$ ? Would this be convex? Would you evaluate the limit you mention using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @texmex: yes to both questions.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Which software do you use to get plots like the above? Do you know any freeware that I can use to get graphs of complicated functions?

Comment: @texmex: I use Mathematica, but you may use GNUplot or any free CAS that is able to interface with GNUplot, like Sage.

Comment: Could you point out a way to prove this without numerical methods? I am trying calculus and seem to get stuck. Proof that this is convex: $F(x)=x^2+xϕ(x)/Φ(x)$

Answer (score 0):

This graph of the various distribution functions should help demonstrate the convexity visually. Hope this helps. Thanks for all the pointers and useful suggestions.[image]